# Generating 3D map from Lidar data

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a rosbag file of Velodyne 64. My question is that how I can generate a 3D map from that rosbag file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325771/generating-3d-map-from-lidar-data/) by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2019-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-06-14**:
What have you tried so far? Is your lidar sensor moving? Do you have any other sensors in the rosbag as well? What sort of map do you need to generate?

We're happy to help, but you're going to have to give us a lot more information.

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-14**:
My lidar sensor is moving and I have only sensor information of Lidar sensor in rosbag and i wanted to generate map for autonomous driving and I have odometry information also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried 3D Localization and mapping using `hdl_graph_slam`. Just using the Lidar scan and odometry and I was able to localize the sensor.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) with karma: 46 on 2021-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1